# How to add image to a recyclerview without creating another class?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I add an image from drawables to a RecyclerView. I tried to add by using the method below:

```
names.add(R.drawables.image, "Image1");
```

but it gives me error.

Is there any alternative for adding image into the arraylist without creating another class.

Comment: post code and logcat please

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2131165305, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:147)
        at com.example.david.location.live.rempractice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:127)

Comment: Hi Hassan, Please post the whole class you are working with,

Comment: @HassanChaudhary Check out the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** Please follow.

**Step1:** Declare a Global Object.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> imgArrayList;
```

**Step2:** Initialize

```
imgArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Step3:** Add your Drawables in two ways.

1. **First Way:** Directly add images one by one.

   ```
   imgArrayList.add(R.drawable.image1);
   imgArrayList.add(R.drawable.image2);
   imgArrayList.add(R.drawable.image3);
   ..... etc etc
   ```
2. **Second Way:** Make an array of **int** as shown below:

   ```
   int imgList[] = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3}
   ```

then,

```
imgArrayList.addAll(imgList);
```

That's it, Now you choose which you want to use. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

To bring an image from drawables you have to have the context in the adapter so that you can use the method:

```
context.getDrawable(R.drawable.image)
```

But this will force you to send the context to the adapter or you have to use the very same method(getDrawable(R.drawable.image)) directly from inside the activity launching the adapter like that:

```
getDrawable(R.drawable.image)
```

I know that this does not sound helpful because you need the images in the adapter so
all what you have to do is preparing the images list in the activity, then send that in the constructor of the Adapter

Answer (score 0):

`names.add(R.drawables.image, "Image1");`

Assuming `names` is a String ArrayList, you're trying to add "Image1" to index `R.drawables.image` (which is a big number, in your case `2131165305`)

To fix your issue, you can create a List of Integer values and *only* add the drawable identifier, so

```
ArrayList<Integer> drawableIds = new ArrayList<>();
drawableIds.add(R.drawable.image1);
drawableIds.add(R.drawable.image2);
```

then set your image like

```
// add a for loop here or whatever
imageView.setImageResource(drawableIds.get(i));
```